# unable to run python program in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, python-3.6

i am having a problem while running my python program in windows 10 64 bit.
i followed writing "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" also but it still shows file not specified.[there is a screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdPns.png)

Comment: I think as your screenshot is saying it is attempting to use another file to execute  your program. Hence first of all save your file as .py and then open the command window in the same directory and then type python filename.py

Comment: This is not an tutorial site. Go to Google and search for Python tutorials and learn the basics. Come back if you have a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow some advice:

1. Change your file from `.txt` to `.py`. (new 1.txt to new1.py).
2. Remove spaces in your file, it is a good practice.
3. Add a proper header in your python script:

   ```
   #! python
   print("Hi")
   ```
4. Make sure that you have a python3 installed in your operating system. Open your command line and type:

   ```
   python -V
   ```
5. Open your Command Line, go to the path of your python script and run `python <file>.py`

   ```
   python new1.py
   ```